# Illegitmate inference in solving a linear equation (which one?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the following five ways of solving the equation $3(r - 5) = 24$:

(1):

$$3(r - 5) = 24$$
$$\frac{3}{3}(r - 5) = \frac{24}{3}$$
$$r - 5 = 8$$
$$r = 8 + 5$$
$$r = 13$$

(2):

$$3(r - 5) = 24$$
$$3r - 15 = 24$$
$$3r = 24 + 15$$
$$3r = 39$$
$$\frac{3}{3}r = \frac{39}{3}$$
$$r = 13$$

(3):

$$3(r - 5) = 24$$
$$\frac{3r - 15}{3} = \frac{24}{3}$$
$$\frac{3r}{3} - \frac{15}{3} = \frac{24}{3}$$
$$r - \frac{15}{3} = \frac{24}{3}$$
$$r - 5 = 8$$
$$r = 8 + 5$$
$$r = 13$$

(4):

$$3(r - 5) = 24$$
$$3r - 15 = 24$$
$$\frac33r - 15 = \frac{24}{3}$$
$$r - 15 = 8$$
$$r = 8 + 15$$
$$r = 23$$

(5):

$$3(r - 5) = 24$$
$$\frac{3r - 15}{3} = \frac{24}{3}$$
$$r - 15 = 8$$
$$r = 8 + 15$$
$$r = 23$$

(1)-(3) are obviously correct. But: Why do (4) and (5) give the incorrect solution to the equation? Which steps of inference in (4) and (5) are illegitimate and why?

Comment: What is the purpose of parentheses?

Comment: If you're hinting at order of operations then I don't know how you would go about solving $(r - 5)$, since you can't subtract anything from a variable. Or are you talking about expanding $3(r - 5)$?

Comment: true, and perhaps my comment was inappropriate as the error seems to be a misapplication of the Distributive principle. For example, in (5) the division by 3 (or alternatively the multiplication by $1/3$) needs to be applied to both $3r$ and $-15$. $$\frac{3r-15}{3} = r-5$$

Answer (score 1):

Here are the errors:

4: going from the second line to the third you divided by 3, but only the first term.

5: going from the second line to the third you divided by 3, but only the first term.

In both cases, you calculated $\frac{a+b}{c}$ as $\frac{a}{c}+b$, which is incorrect.  It should be $\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}$.

Comment: Why in both (4) and (5) in lines #3 and #2 respectively, canceling 3 does not work? Why do I have to divide both terms? Why can't I divide a single term on both sides of the equation as adding say $3$ to $x - 3 = 6$ such that $x - 3 + 3 = 6 + 3$? Take e.g., $4x = 20$; $\frac{4}{4}x = \frac{20}{4}$; $x = 5$. Thanks.

Comment: There are specific rules for cancelling.  $\frac{ac+bc}{c}=a+b$ is valid.  $\frac{ac+bc}{c}=a+bc$ is NOT valid.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That seems to be a rule for cases where the numerator is a sum, which is not the case with (5). Anyway, come to think of it, the explanation I needed was this: in the present case of (5), canceling only works when the numerator of a fraction is a product! $3r - 15$ is a difference, so canceling $3$ in $\frac{3r - 15}{3}$ is illegitimate. But perhaps I am wrong, still. (4) is still puzzling to me, however.

Answer (score 1):

You have already been told where your errors are, but if you had wanted to find out on your own you could have plugged in some value for $r$ and looked at when the two sides changed in different ways.

Using the known solution it is a question of when they stop being equal, but sometimes it is worth it to use the method when you don't know the solution so it is worth knowing what can happen in general.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$x+y=z\implies \frac{x+y}{k}=\frac{z}{k}~,~k\neq 0\not\Rightarrow \frac{x}{k}+y=\frac{z}{k}\textrm{ or }x+\frac{y}{k}=\frac{z}{k}$$

The correct implication is, for $k\neq 0$,

$$\frac{x+y}{k}=\frac{z}{k}\implies \frac{x}{k}+\frac{y}{k}=\frac{z}{k}$$